# How to remove default value from non nullable column in code first entity framework

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, default-value

I have created a table with column like this

```
builder.Property(b => b.IndicatorPriority)
    .HasColumnName("IndicatorPriority") //Optional, Priority
    .HasColumnType("INT")
    .IsRequired();
```

I did not specify any default value for this column but the migration generated using `add-migration` this, has default value

```
migrationBuilder.AddColumn<int>(
    name: "IndicatorPriority",
    schema: "Internal",
    table: "IndicatorStrategyMapping",
    type: "INT",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: 0);
```

How can I remove this default value binding in code first?

I tried adding these lines in my column definition

```
.HasDefaultValue(null)
```

and

```
.HasDefaultValueSql(null)
```

but no migration change is detected by these lines.

How can I delete the default value link for non nullable columns?

**Update**

As asked in one comment, so to clarify, I do want a **non nullable** column with **no default value** to force user supply value for this column while inserting records

Comment: I can't understand the problem, you using 'IsRequired' property and also want remove default value? What is the sense?
try to remove  'IsRequired' property.

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko - And I am not getting why it is so hard to get the question, is it some unexpected requirement to have a required column but no default value to force user provide the value while inserting record?

Comment: I believe if your user will try insert model without required field he will get a validation error message.
But in your case you running migration script, and it's automatically inserting value to the required field.
That's it why I can't unterstand what is the problem everything works as expected.

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko - Which scripts are inserting values to the required field? The script I posted is the schema creation script and not the insertion script. And when I insert the object without this value using Entity framework, it does not give me any error but takes the default value.

Comment: Okay, so what is the goal? 
If you set 'not null' and 'no default value', so what value should be there?)

Comment: @SergiyMatvienko - Whatever value user wants to put in while inserting the record.

Comment: Try to take a look here: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/6035

Comment: Any luck with this one?  I have exactly the same problem.  Silly EF generating defaults when I don't want them.  It seems to do this for Guid and DateTime.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the part <del>`defaultValue: 0`</del> before executing the command `database update`

Comment: That file is generated automatically. So I do not want to change it manually. I want to do it in the right way so that the EF will generate the change properly

Answer (score 1):

So as answered by @serhii-matvienko here [link to comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68282014/how-to-remove-default-value-from-non-nullable-column-in-code-first-entity-framew#comment120687725_68282014) we can conclude:

This happens when the developer adds a column ta an existing table, and the new column is NOT NULL. If it does not specify a default value the DB will remove all rows from that table because the new column will invalidate each row (can't insert a row where that new column is null).

To make the job easier for the developer (specially for new commers) they make the assumption the the column will be filled-up with the CLR Type default value, for ex:

- Int will have default value 0
- Date will have default value '0001-01-01 00:00:00'
- ...

So I suggest that the developer take a manual migration edit on this change because EF Core always add a default value. It is the responsibility of the programmer to decide what to do with this new column. He must define the proper way to do it for each use case, one of the following actions:

**A)** let that snippet has it is, at the end of the migration Up method redefine the column to have the default value has not null so new rows will require the user to insert a proper value but the existing ones will be pre-filled with 0 (this will not work if the column is a foreign key);

**B)** change the current snippet to let NULLs in the new column, make a SQL script that will fill-up this column for all rows of current table (like getting the foreign key value), after having the values change the type of the column to NOT NULL.